# Reset CSS messing with layout

Tags: html, css, css-reset

So I've found that my site has a bunch of inconsistencies between browsers (as to be expected)

I've implementing reset.css into my style sheet and it works with most of the issues except what seems to be the padding. When it's added it pushes the header down the page. The good news is it does this consistently through each browser haha

So what can be done to keep the header in place rather then it bumping down?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try using `box-sizing` CSS property, more in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: I would really avoid using tables for layout, as you have throughout. There's no need for them, and they're going to make your life much harder in the long run (e.g., you have explicit widths and heights set in the markup, impervious to your CSS styling).

Comment: So you're saying it's not a browser issue, as it's the same in each browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) as your css reset instead, it's worked for me and fixes padding for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` file adds a `vertical-align: baseline;` which messes up your layout. IMHO if you do use a reset, then you need to explicitly define paddings, margins etc.